# RGoogleDocs (or RCurl) giving SSL certificate problem

Tags: r, ssl-certificate, google-docs

I was using one of my favorite R packages today to read data from a google spreadsheet. It would not work. This problem is occurring on all my machines (I use windows) and it appears to be a new problem. I am using Version: 0.4-1 of RGoogleDocs

```
library(RGoogleDocs)
ps <-readline(prompt="get the password in ")
sheets.con = getGoogleDocsConnection(getGoogleAuth("fxxxh@gmail.com", ps, service ="wise"))
ts2=getWorksheets("OnCall",sheets.con)
```

And this is what I get after running the last line.

> Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
>     SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I did some reading and came across some interesting, but not useful to me at least, information.

[When I try to interact with a URL via https, I get an error of the form](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html)
[Curl: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK](http://ademar.name/blog/2006/04/curl-ssl-certificate-problem-v.html)

I got the very big picture message but did not know how to implement the solution in my script. I dropped the following line before getWorksheets.

```
x = getURLContent("https://www.google.com", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

That did not work so I tried

```
ts2=getWorksheets("OnCall",sheets.con,ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

That also did not work.

Interestingly enough, the following line works

```
getDocs(sheets.con,folders = FALSE)
```

What do you suggest I try to get it working again? Thanks.

Comment: Any salvation on this? I ran into the same problem...

Comment: I no longer have the problem. I posted what works for me down below. Please tell me how it goes for you.

Answer (score 3):

I no longer have this problem. I do not quite remember the timeline of exactly when I overcame the problem and cannot remember who helped me get here but here is a typical session which works.

```
library(RGoogleDocs)
if(exists("ps")) print("got password, keep going") else ps <-readline(prompt="get the password in ")  #conditional password asking
options(RCurlOptions = list(capath = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
sheets.con = getGoogleDocsConnection(getGoogleAuth("fjh@gmail.com", ps, service ="wise")) 
#WARNING: this would prevent curl from detecting a 'man in the middle' attack
ts2=getWorksheets("name of workbook here",sheets.con)
names(ts2)
sheet.1 <-sheetAsMatrix(ts2$"Sheet 1",header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE, trim=TRUE) #Get one sheet
other <-sheetAsMatrix(ts2$"whatever name of tab",header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE, trim=TRUE) #Get other sheet
```

Does it help you?

Comment: works like a charm, the important line is the RCurlOptions I figured out. Thx for the solution!

Comment: yes x10000 - this took me hours to find while trying to connect to dropbox in R

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the [certificate bundle](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/net/curl-ca-bundle/Portfile) installed. I installed those on OS X. You can also find them on the [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) site

Comment: Thank you for your response. I suspected that RCurl would have installed the certificate bundle. So I searched my hardrive for cacert.pem and there it was  
C:\Program Files (x86)\R\R-2.11.1\library\RCurl\CurlSSL\cacert.pem

Doesn't that mean that I have it?